# Returning rows that contain two values within the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills.

I have a table called `problems`. It looks like:

```
id  | pid |  problem_list_id
-----------------------------------
1   | 159 | 16
2   | 159 | 4
3   | 10  | 16
4   | 565 | 90
5   | 565 | 4
6   | 122 | 12
```

I'd like to query `pid` that have a problem_id of BOTH 16 and 4.

```
SELECT
    YEAR(pbd.date_created), 
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    patient_booking_data pbd inner join problems p on pbd.pid = p.pid
WHERE p.problem_list_id in (16,4)
GROUP BY YEAR(pbd.date_created)
ORDER BY YEAR(pbd.date_created)
```

This obviously would hit 16 or 4. I need pid's with BOTH 16 AND 4.

When I try using:

```
WHERE (p.problem_list_id = 16 AND p.problem_list_id = 4)
```

That doesn't yield any results.

I can use something like:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(pbd.date_created), 
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    patient_booking_data pbd inner join problems p on pbd.pid = p.pid
WHERE p.problem_list_id = 16
      AND pbd.pid in (SELECT pid FROM problems where problem_list_id = 4)
GROUP BY YEAR(pbd.date_created)
ORDER BY YEAR(pbd.date_created)
```

But using a nested `select` seems like overkill.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure why your query is different than your data table?

But with your data table you use `HAVING COUNT()`

```
SELECT pid 
FROM problems
WHERE problem_list_id in (16,4)
GROUP BY pid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT problem_list_id) = 2
```

I use distinct in case a pid can have muliple occurence of `16 or 2` otherwise just `COUNT(*)` will be enough

Maybe you need something like this. Using cte to calculate the pid first and then return the `patient_booking`

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT pid 
    FROM problems
    WHERE problem_list_id in (16,4)
    GROUP BY pid
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT problem_list_id) = 2
)
SELECT
    YEAR(pbd.date_created), 
    COUNT(*)
FROM patient_booking_data pbd 
JOIN CTE c on pbd.pid = c.pid
GROUP BY YEAR(pbd.date_created)
ORDER BY YEAR(pbd.date_created)
```